# How to use text compression in React js Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jdeveloper

Currently I don't have any idea about Compression and Gzip.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should do some research then so you can ask more specific questions. Nobody is going to write a tutorial for you here on these topics. That is not what Stack Overflow is for. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)